# Different result from different sample split method?

Tags: r

I'm practicing the different methods of splitting datasets. However, the split observation numbers have different results. Isn't the result of the observation numbers with two functions should be same? Since the split ratio and original data set are the same?

Here's my code

```
##split data set with caTools
set.seed(144)
split.5<-sample.split(CTR$CTR,0.7)
ctr.test<-filter(CTR,split.5==FALSE)
ctr.train<-filter(CTR,split.5==TRUE)

##split data set with sample function
train.id=sample(nrow(CTR),0.7*nrow(CTR))
ctr_test=CTR[-train.id,]
ctr_train=CTR[train.id,]
```

according to the result calculated from the calculator, the observation number of `sample` is correct, equal to total observations*0.7.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble understanding the question. Can you show what you expected from the code and what you actually got?  What is CTR$CTR?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of your code, let me know if this isn't what you meant.

```
set.seed(144)
split.5<-sample.split(chickwts$weight,0.7)
ctr.test<-dplyr::filter(chickwts,split.5==FALSE)
ctr.train<-dplyr::filter(chickwts,split.5==TRUE)
set.seed(144)
train.id=sample(nrow(chickwts),0.7*nrow(chickwts))
ctr_test=chickwts[-train.id,]
ctr_train=chickwts[train.id,]
```

And then you can see that

```
  nrow(ctr_test) == nrow(ctr.test)
```

is TRUE.
I think you are asking why you don't end up with the same rows.
That is why the index values where train.id  == TRUE are not the same as the values for split.5.

Using ?Random  will get you more information on random number generation in R.  I didn't look into the code of sample.split() but the documentation doesn't say much about the details of the RNG used.

So if you try this

```
set.seed(144)
split.52<-sample.split(chickwts$weight,0.7)
ctr.test2<-dplyr::filter(chickwts,split.5==FALSE)
ctr.train2<-dplyr::filter(chickwts,split.5==TRUE)
ctr.test2 == ctr.test
set.seed(144)
train.id2=sample(nrow(chickwts),0.7*nrow(chickwts))
ctr_test2=chickwts[-train.id,]
ctr_train2=chickwts[train.id,]
ctr_test == ctr_test2
```

You see that each method works as you expected but they are working somewhat differently.

Update:
A closer look reveals that `sample.split()` uses `runif()`. In contrast `sample()` relies on much lower level code. This is an article that can get you started on what that means:
https://datascienceconfidential.github.io/r/2017/12/28/how-to-read-source-code-internal-r-function.html